# How to insert fa-fa icon to search box

Tags: icons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl7Jh.png)I need a little help with a search form icon.

```
<div class="top">
        <div class="large">
          <div class="b1">
            <div class="label"><?php _e('What are you looking for?', 'veronika'); ?></div>
            <div class="box">
              <?php if (osc_get_preference('item_ajax', 'veronika_theme') == 1) { ?>
                <div id="item-picker">
                  <input type="text" name="sPattern" class="pattern" placeholder="<?php _e('Samsung S7 Edge...', 'veronika'); ?>" value="<?php echo Params::getParam('sPattern'); ?>" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what are the issues you've encountered?

Comment: I have tried using class tags
<input type="text" name="sPattern" class="fa fa-search " placeholder="<?php _e('Samsung S7 Edge...', 'veronika'); ?>
Does not work